# java.io.FileNotFoundException в андроиде

Tags: java, android, сервер, retrofit, запрос

Ошибка:

```
07-24 07:11:05.903 15734-15734/com.project.samuliak.psychogram E/samuliak: Upload error:java.io.FileNotFoundException: /external/images/media/725: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Я выбираю картинку из галерее, тогда отправляю её на сервер. Но в логе вот такая ошибка.
Запрос:

```
 Call<String> call = service.uploadFile(descriptionString, body);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call,
                                   Response<String> response) {
                path[0] = response.body();
                Log.e("samuliak", "Succesful:"+response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("samuliak", "Upload error:"+t.toString());
            }
        });
```

retrofit api:

```
// Загрузка фото
@Multipart
@POST("psychologist/upload")
Call<String> uploadFile(@Part("description") String description,
                          @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

Контролер на сервере, который принимает файл:

```
 /*
Загрузка фото (!)
 */
@RequestMapping(value="/psychologist/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("name") String name,
                                             @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        String path = "";
        try {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            path = new File(name + "-uploaded").getPath();
            System.out.println(path);
            BufferedOutputStream stream =
                    new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(name + "-uploaded")));
            stream.write(bytes);

            stream.close();
            return  path;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Вам не удалось загрузить " + name + " => " + e.getMessage());
            return "Вам не удалось загрузить " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        return "Вам не удалось загрузить " + name + " потому что файл пустой.";
    }
}
```

Помогите!

**UPDATE**

[Spring, метод в контролере не правильно работает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/547964/spring-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82)

Comment: разрешение на чтение external есть? Какая версия Android?

Comment: да, разрешение есть. Андроид 5.1

Comment: Хотя на данный момент эту ошибку я исправил. Но проблема из сервером, вот ссылка на новый вопрос: добавил в главный пост