# Spring, метод в контролере не правильно работает

Tags: java, android, сервер, retrofit

Я отправляю фотку на сервер
Код отправки:

```
Call<String> call = service.uploadFile(descriptionString, body);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call,
                               Response<String> response) {
            path[0] = response.body();
            Log.e("samuliak", "Succesful:"+response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("samuliak", "Upload error:"+t.toString());
        }
    });
```

Вот API ретрофита:

```
@Multipart
@POST("psychologist/upload")
Call<String> uploadFile(@Part("name") String description,
                          @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

А вот метод контролера:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/psychologist/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("name") String name,
                                             @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        String path = "";
        try {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            path = new File(name + "-uploaded").getPath();
            System.out.println(path);
            BufferedOutputStream stream =
                    new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(name + "-uploaded")));
            stream.write(bytes);

            stream.close();
            return  path;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Вам не удалось загрузить " + name + " => " + e.getMessage());
            return "Вам не удалось загрузить " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        return "Вам не удалось загрузить " + name + " потому что файл пустой.";
    }
}
```

Я понимаю, что неправильно сформирован метод, поэтому прошу разъяснить мне, как правильно! Очень хочу это знать, самому разобраться очень сложно и уже 4 часа сижу и мучаюсь! Помогите!

**UPDATE**

```
    08-04 13:55:02.670 24439-24439/com.project.samuliak.psychogram E/samuliak: Activity result in Registr..
08-04 13:55:02.692 24439-24439/com.project.samuliak.psychogram E/samuliak: path from act.result > /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160624_141505_1.jpg
08-04 13:55:02.705 24439-24454/com.project.samuliak.psychogram I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 482(34KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(16KB) LOS objects, 39% free, 3MB/6MB, paused 6.386ms total 15.981ms
08-04 13:55:02.711 24439-24451/com.project.samuliak.psychogram W/CursorWrapperInner: Cursor finalized without prior close()
08-04 13:55:02.779 24439-24439/com.project.samuliak.psychogram E/samuliak: uploadFile. End.
08-04 13:55:02.808 24439-24478/com.project.samuliak.psychogram W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-04 13:55:02.808 24439-24478/com.project.samuliak.psychogram W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe2026ee0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
08-04 13:55:03.045 24439-24439/com.project.samuliak.psychogram E/samuliak: not succesful > Bad Request
08-04 13:55:03.045 24439-24439/com.project.samuliak.psychogram E/samuliak: body > :null
```

UPDATE Update Cataline Log

```
05-Aug-2016 10:42:31.506 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl.useContextualLobCreation HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Comment: В чем именно состоит ваш вопрос? Как вы поняли, что метод работает неправильно?

Comment: При отправки файла на сервер, то колбек кидает в "onFailure"

Comment: Ну, а что выводит t.toString()? Или полный очет - t.printStackTrace() что выведет?

Comment: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1
вот что выводит

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в том, что Retrofit ожидает от сервера JSON, а вы возвращаете строку.

```
@ResponseBody public String uploadFile(...)  { ... }
```

Создайте класс-обертку для строки:

```
public class StringResponse {
    private String value;
    public String getValue() { return value; }
    public void setValue(String value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

Используйте его для возврата строки в контроллере

```
@RequestMapping(value="/psychologist/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public StringResponse uploadFile(@RequestParam("name") String name,
                                             @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

    // ... ваш код ...

    StringResponse resp = new StringResponse();
    resp.setValue(path);
    return resp;

    // ... ваш код ...
}
```

и интерфейсе ретрофита

```
@Multipart
@POST("psychologist/upload")
Call<StringResponse> uploadFile(@Part("name") String description, @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

---

Когда это заработает - позаботьтесь об обработке ошибок. Добавьте в `StringResponse` поле `error`, в которое будете выставлять текст ошибки. `value` в таком случае можно выставить в `null`. Или еще добавить поле с флагом неуспешного завершения `boolean failed`.

После этого вы можете захотеть обобщить класс для любых результатов, возвращаемых серевером. Также стоит подумать о том, чтобы избавить его от сеттеров, сделать все поля финальными и добавить удобные фабричные методы.

```
public class ServerResponse<T> {
    private final T value;
    private final boolean failed;
    private final String errorMsg;

    public T getValue() { return value; }
    public boolean isFailed() { return failed; }
    public String getErrorMsg() { return errorMsg; }

    public static ServerResponse<T> ok(T value) {
        ServerResponse<T> resp = new ServerResponse<>();
        resp.value = value;
        return resp;    
    }

    public static ServerResponse<T> error(String errorMsg) {
        ServerResponse<T> resp = new ServerResponse<>();
        resp.errorMsg = errorMsg;
        resp.failed = true;
        return resp;    
    }
}
```

Так вы получите универсальный класс-обертку, в который можно будет добавлять служебные поля (коды ошибок, пагинацию, таймстампы) по мере необходимости, не затрагивая основное содержимое в поле `value`.

```
    // ... ваш код ...

    return StringResponse.ok(path);

    // ... ваш код ...

    return StringResponse.error("Вам не удалось загрузить " + name + " потому что файл пустой.");
```

Comment: к сожалению, не работает ( получается ошибка "Bad Request"

Comment: без стектрейсов я ничем не могу помочь

Comment: добавил в первый пост

Comment: я имел в виду стектрейс сервера

Comment: почему то нет никаких трейсов ( при помощи System.out.println() ничего не выводит, даже в других методах . В чем может быть проблема ? Эдинственное что есть, так это строчка из Tomcat Cataline Log (добавил в главный пост)

Comment: ой, перепутал посты (((